# Onesignal adding '[modified]' to header or body of my notifications for some users

Tags: react-native, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

I've had a few users reporting that their notification data contains [modified] at the end of the header of the body of their notifcations.

I have no idea where this could come from as it only appears for some users and I'm unable to reproduce it on my end.

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Figured out the issue, check your NotificationService.m file. the "self.bestAttemptContent.title" has [modified] prepended to the message.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the NotificationService file and look the code             `bestAttemptContent.title = "\(bestAttemptContent.title) [modified] "`
and just remove [modified] from this like this code

```
bestAttemptContent.title = "\(bestAttemptContent.title) "
```

and then run again